# Show total sales in the product title everywhere in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I'm building an art gallery with woocommerce.
each product has a limited number of prints (for example: 100).
I'm looking for a way of showing in the product title, the number of the current print based of the number of prints already sold, so for example if 20 prints where sold, the product name would be "NAME OF PRINT - PRINT NUMBER 21"

So far I have been searching the web for a solution, but could not find the right way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: The following code will display in single product pages and archives pages the products sold quantity:

```
// Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_title', 2 );
function custom_single_product_title() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_title_custom', 5 );
}

// Shop and archives pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_loop_product_title', 2 );
function custom_loop_product_title() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
    add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'product_title_custom', 10 );
}

function product_title_custom() {
    global $product;

    $sales = $product->get_total_sales();
    $single_text = __( "PRINT NUMBER", "woocommerce" ) . ' ' . $sales;

    if( is_product() ) : // Single product pages
    ?>
        <h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span> - <span><?php echo $single_text; ?></span>
        </h1>
    <?php
    else : // Loop product pages (shop and archives)
    ?>
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><?php the_title(); echo "($sales)"; ?></h2>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

To display the products sold quantity **in item name cart and checkout pages**:

```
// Add to cart items names the total sales
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_product_title_name', 20, 3 );
function custom_product_title_name( $cart_item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    // The product object from cart item
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $sales = $product->get_total_sales();
    $text = __( "PRINT NUMBER", "woocommerce" ) . ' ';

    return $cart_item_name . ' - ' . $text . $sales;
}
```

To display the products sold quantity in item name **order pages and email notifications**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_single_excerpt_to_order_item', 10, 3 );
function add_single_excerpt_to_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ){
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $sales = $product->get_total_sales();
    $text = __( "PRINT NUMBER", "woocommerce" ) . ' ';

    return $item_name . ' - ' . $text . $sales;
}
```

To display the products sold quantity in **admin order edit pages**, is not possible to display it the same way… I has to be under the product title in a separated line:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'total_sales_before_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function total_sales_before_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ){
    // Only on backend order edit pages
    if( ! ( is_admin() && $item->is_type('line_item') ) ) return;

    echo '<p><em>' .__( "Total sales" ) . ': ' . $product->get_total_sales() . '</em></p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that.
This actually shows the remaining stock count rather than the next item on the list. 
I could not get it to work on shop and archive pages, but this is not that important.
However, is there a way to pass the number as the products name to the cart and checkout pages?

Comment: @fafchook I have updated my code with the total sales… Your title was not clear… I have added some more code to my answer for cart and checkout pages… Please check it

Comment: WOW, this is great! i know i was not clear enough and i apologize for that. this now works perfect, but i was sure it would send the order email details with the new parameters, but it only sends the products name. 
Should i change it in the email templates?  
Anyway, i could not thank you enough.

Comment: One last question, you can say no :)
Is it possible to see the number with the product name in the woocommerce orders page?

Comment: children first!
Backend wordpress menu - woocommerce - orders + single order page when editing the order

Comment: @fafchook I have added some code for backend… For order admin list is not possible as the items are not displayed in it (and an order can have many items)…

Comment: I see. Thanks again for all your effort!

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, i have a question i'm hoping you can answer:
Is it possible to use this code with variations? that the number would show next to the variation and not the title, and still pass on to the cart-checkout and email?

Comment: @fafchook Yes it should be possible (not with this code), as it's much more complicated if you plan to have this on single product pages, as jQuery/php code will be needed and this info will be displayed only when a variation is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into woocommerce product detail page's `title`.

For default page structure and hook you can see [**here**](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/)

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title',5);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_title_with_sold',5);


function woocommerce_title_with_sold() {
?>
    <h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">
        <span>
            <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo $units_sold = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'total_sales', true ); ?>
        </span>
    </h1>
<?php
}
```

If you want to show everywhere you need to look for woocomerce hooks/filters/actions

Comment: Wow, this is great, thank you so much!
Is there a way that i can pass this data to the cart and check out, as the product's name?

Comment: you need another hook for cart products title.